# Converting a IntPtr bluetooth socket instance to a native monodroid BlueToothSocket?

Tags: android, java-native-interface, xamarin.android

I'm using JNI to get a IntPtr to a bluetooth connection method. The code is:

```
IntPtr createRfcommSocket = JNIEnv.GetMethodID(device.Class.Handle, "createRfcommSocket", "(I)Landroid/bluetooth/BluetoothSocket;");
IntPtr socket = JNIEnv.CallObjectMethod(device.Handle, createRfcommSocket, new JValue(1));
```

Is there anyway to convert the IntPtr socket to a native monodroid BlueToothSocket?

I need this to offer a single interface to a create bluetooth socket method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there anyway to convert the IntPtr socket to a native monodroid BlueToothSocket?

If by "native monodroid BlueToothSocket" you mean [BluetoothSocket](http://androidapi.xamarin.com/?link=T:Android.Bluetooth.BluetoothSocket), then you use the [Java.Lang.Object.GetObject<T>()](http://androidapi.xamarin.com/?link=M%3aJava.Lang.Object.GetObject%7b;T%7d;(System.IntPtr%2cAndroid.Runtime.JniHandleOwnership)) method:

```
var msocket = Java.Lang.Object.GetObject<Android.Bluetooth.BluetoothSocket>(socket, JniHandleOwnership.TransferLocalRef);
```